# Map VS2008 keyboard shortcuts to Eclipse

Tags: visual-studio-2008, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configure Eclipse to use VS.Net shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213205/configure-eclipse-to-use-vs-net-shortcuts)

I mostly work in VS2008 but I need to do some java work in Eclipse. Is there an easy and fast way to map the VS2008 keyboard shortcuts to Eclipse?

For example, I want to map F11 in Eclipse to "step info" instead of its default of F5 but don't want to have to map each and every shortcut manually...

Comment: Re why is this closed as a duplicate - This was the original Q - there is a causality issue with the indicated duplicate - this ID = 16704, duplicate ID = 2213205 (Feb 6 2010)

Comment: As the original poster of this question I agree that the subsequent one, in theory, should have been marked as a duplicate. However, that should have happened when the duplicate was first asked. Now the duplicate has a much better answer than this question so it makes perfect sense to keep the duplicate and not this one.

Answer (score 1):

How are the Eclipse settings saved? Perhaps you could simply adapt [this macro](http://xona.com/2005/08/02.html) and load the resulting file into Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Eclipse have a predefined keyboard setup for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to install the CDT for eclipse (the standard C/C++ plugin).

Then when you go to Preferences->General->Keys you will have a "Microsoft Visual Studio" option in the dropdown.