# Configure Eclipse to use VS.Net shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I've started doing some Python Programming using Eclipse.  However, I'm a .Net programmer and I'm use to the keyboard shortcuts in VS.Net 2008.  Is there any quick way to reconfigure VS.Net to use the visual studio shortcuts.  I've found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704/map-vs2008-keyboard-shortcuts-to-eclipse), but the suggested methods don't work.  I've installed CDT and selected the Visual Studio Keys, but it doesn't seem to change any of the key mappings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's strange because after installing the C/C++ Development Tools (CDT):

[alt text http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/4002/screenshot001ey.png](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/4002/screenshot001ey.png)

And picking up the **Microsoft Visual Studio** scheme (from **Windows > Preferences > General > Keys**):

[alt text http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/9844/screenshot002r.png](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/9844/screenshot002r.png)

My binding are definitely altered as shown below (ok it's just a small example but it illustrates the change and all bindings mentioned by @VonC are there):

[alt text http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1401/screenshot002gd.png](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1401/screenshot002gd.png)

Comment: This did not work for me. I went through the steps and got the "Visual Studio" option for my keys configuration, but it did not switch to my typical shortcuts.

Comment: Did not work for me as I expected either. Installing CDT adds new commands for C/C++ development but does not modify existing Java command shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

If the CDT Visual Studio mapping does not work, you need to import custom shortcut files for the usual Visual Studio shortcuts.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200499/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse) mentions [this article](http://code.vn720.com/2009/10/02/visual-studio-key-bindings-for-eclipse/), with this minimal set:

- New PHP File: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- Next Editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Previous Editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Find and Replace: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find Next: <kbd>F3</kbd>
- Find Previous: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
- Open Search Dialog: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- New File: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- Go to line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- File.Close: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>