# change eclipse shortcuts to match Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, configure

Is there a way to change keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse to match those in Visual Studio 2010?

I am a C# developer and I am used to Visual Studio shortcuts. I am now using Eclipse to do some Java programming. It is fun, but painful because my brain is hard-wired :).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

after installing the C/C++ Development Tools (CDT) there should be Visual Studio scheme available
(from Windows > Preferences > General > Keys)

more informations (with screenshots) can be found on 
[Configure Eclipse to use VS.Net shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213205/configure-eclipse-to-use-vs-net-shortcuts)

I've just tried it using Spring's eclipse distribution (spring source tool suite)
and it works

Comment: Does not work in Eclipse Indigo (8.0.2). Just tried: Installed CDT, Switched to VisualStudio scheme, exported shortcuts to CSV file, switched back to Default scheme, exported shortcuts to CSV file, sorted both files in Excel, compared by BeyondCompare -- verdict: the files are identical. (They were not identical before sorting). 

Do not want to be negative, but this info may save somebody from hassle of installing CDT. :-)

Comment: Clarification to my previous comment: It *does not work* as I expected. Installing CDT adds many new commands which work in C/C++ source editor and some new commands which work in C/C++ debugger but it does not modify existing command shortcuts in Java such as Debug StepInto(F5), StepOver(F6) - (F11 and F10 in VS).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Visual Studio option removes a number of useful Eclipse shortcuts, for example ctrl-shift-F to format a java document.

Comment: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200499/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse solved my problem. I'm using eclipse IDE for Java, but wanted same key bindings as Visual Studio for C#.

Comment: On the last comment: it doesn't bring all the bindings like F12(open declaration) or such, so you are on your own in the end to put your favorite bindings there. At least you can do it on pretty much any IDE. Learn one IDE's shortcuts or make your own and bring them to any IDE you use. It's some amount of work, but after it's done you are more productive with the IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

should be very easy

- open preferences (Window->Preferences)
- type keys in the search box
- locate General->Keys
- type the command you want to modify
- modify the binding
- type your binding in the search list to make sure no other command is using the same binding

tadaa!

p.s.: a c# ide plugin for eclipse would be great. i'm a java/eclipse rcp developer, but i like c# as language. i haven't done anything serious yet because of visual studio. it feels like some old java ide from the 90's.

Comment: The issue is we need to do the 'tadaa!' for every key stroke needed :( Is there a csv file we could import?

Answer (score -6):

Write a plug-in for Eclipse - it is not too difficult.

Comment: Good grief!  Writing a plug-in just to change key bindings!!  Developing software is supposed to make things easier... lol

Comment: Read the post carefully my friend :)The suggestion was in relation to the user's query on C#.